# How long does it take to process a big text file?

Tags: java, algorithm, random, big-o

I have a big text file containing names.

The objective is to generate a random name (two random names from the file).

Considering that the file has about 8k lines, with one name per line, is it efficient processor-wise to try and get a random line from this File? Is it a long process to use, therefore inneficient on runtime?

I plan to use the following method to get the random name

```
 public static String choose(File f) throws FileNotFoundException
 {
 String result = null;
 Random rand = new Random();
 int n = 0;
 for(Scanner sc = new Scanner(f); sc.hasNext(); )
 {
    ++n;
    String line = sc.nextLine();
    if(rand.nextInt(n) == 0)
       result = line;         
 }

 return result;      
}
```

A rookie analysis of this code makes me think it runs in about **O(n)** time

But I'm testing it with a lower number of Strings (original file currently not done yet, around 150 names for test-purposes).

**Is this an efficient way to generate the random names?**

@Edit

Efficiency is important, considering that I want to generate the name on a low amount of time.

Comment: If RAM is not an issue, then you can just load the text file as a whole and store each line in a `HashMap`, this only speeds up things if you need to get multiple random names.

Comment: If each String is ~20bytes that is only 160kb of memory which is small for anything you will be running Java on. In addition reading from files is really slow compared to reading from memory, if you need to create several names names you should read all of the names into an array and pick an random index.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This depends on if you want to use your function repeatedly (generate many random names) or not.
If not, generate a random numeber within file size, skip to corresponding byte, find nearest line ending a get line.

For help with ´RandomAccessFle´ check: 
https://bitsofinfo.wordpress.com/2009/04/15/how-to-read-a-specific-line-from-a-very-large-file-in-java/

If you need to generate many random names, read the whole file to an ArrayList (8k is far not much).

------- modification to meed btilly's ideas

1. generate random number
2. read fixed length of chars from that point to cover some 5-10 names (lines)
3. split the contents by '\n' to create an array of line contents
4. [0] and [n-1] elements will be incomplete
5. of the other array elements select a random one.

To cover the file ending without bias, add some 10 foobar names to the end of file and repeat the process if that one is selected.

Comment: 8k is not much? Then I have a pretty newbie concept that 8k is a big number :P

Comment: That method of getting a random line will pick lines with odds proportional to the length of the preceding line.  This can be a significant bias.  For an unbiased method you can pick a random location, read a fixed length, pick a random line ending out of that section, and then find the line ending there.  If no line ending is found, try again.

Comment: MoisesCol: Even 8M will still be good, At the moment I am reading an amount of 100MB text files into memory and it is OK. (DNA sequence analysis - running a few seconds).
btilly: You are right, long names are preferred. I did not ellaborate much while answering but the idea is similar. I would improve your idea a bit in an answer.